# Git: Merging a new commit back to master, made against a very old commit

Tags: git, git-merge

I've got a project in git where everything is being done directly on the master branch, with tags being used to mark released versions of the code.
I'm aware that this is not ideal and have been looking at git flows such as this one: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ - However, even using a better setup, I can't easily see a way that a 'hotfix' could be applied to an previous release of the project and committed back to the master branch...

The git repo I'm using has a remote origin and currently just myself and one other developer have clones of it.
The master branch log looks something like this right now:

```
master: A--B--(C)--...--F--G
```

Commit C is tagged as a release point e.g. "v0.2" and I want to change that code base.
I can checkout refs/tags/v0.2 into a new local branch and commit a change to a file (e.g. Main.java in this case), and even tag that commit (Commit H tagged as 'v0.3')

```
master: A--B--(C)--D--...--F--G
v0.2  :        C--(H)
```

But really, I don't want to have a branch hanging around for each version - I just want relevant tags along the master branch. Having tagged commit H as 'v0.3', if I try to delete branch 'v0.2' I get:

> 'error: The branch 'v2' is not fully merged. If you are sure you want
>   to delete it, run 'git branch -D v2'

Okay, so it's not merged back to master but the edited part of Main.java doesn't even exist any more in the latest version, so is this a problem?

I think I can still delete the branch with '-D' and not lose the commit because the commit is still referenced by a tag.

Doing this on a scratch repo and then running 'git log --graph --all' from the master branch shows me:

```
* Commit I
|
* Commit G
...
|
* Commit D
|
|  * Commit H
|/
* Commit C
...
|
* Commit A
```

What problems might I encounter if I leave the history as above?
If not can anyone suggest the best-practice approach to handling this scenario please?

I hope I'm not over-thinking this :-)  Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: The way to solve it is to not do everything directly in master. You don't need an elaborate branching strategy, just branch off of master for anything - features and hotfixes and whatever. If you need to fix something, branch from master, fix it, merge it back in and tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay, so it's not merged back to master but the edited part of Main.java doesn't even exist any more in the latest version, so is this a problem?

Nope.

> I think I can still delete the branch with '-D' and not lose the commit because the commit is still referenced by a tag.

Right. Exactly right.

> What problems might I encounter if I leave the history as above?

If the changes you need from the leaf commits already exist in the mainline, or are no longer relevant, none at all.

Also, if every commit you might want to resuscitate for some reason is reachable from a reference in some repo you can get to when you need it, then nothing is lost.  Nothing says every repo has to have every commit ever (you don't push all your branches, right? Nobody needs to see your wip stuff or your experiments or just plain farting around).

Check shop rules, though.  Administrative procedures can have other concerns than future development needs.

> I can't easily see a way that a 'hotfix' could be applied to an previous release of the project and committed back to the master branch...

The always-works (as in, always leaves a completely correct history) option is, branch off the earliest merged commit introducing the bug, fix it there, merge that to every branch tip that has the bad commit.  Subsequent changes to those might conflict with the fix, and if lots of work has been done on the affected files you might want to check even the apparently successful merges, no text-based vcs can be immune.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that you have two versions, I and H. The changes of H are not going to make it to the latest release, or, if you build the code in H, you won't have the changes of D..G and I.

You *have* to merge them if you want to have both changes.

Of course, if you applied the changes of H to the master, then this is not a problem. You basically did by hand what a merge would otherwise have done. And you can just continue to build new versions. But still, it will look weird and confusing to have this dangling branch, and I would, if I were you, merge it anyway to solve that.

So you don't *have* to delete or merge it, but I would, and I think it's common practice.

Comment: Ah! This is making some sense to me. I've just tried a couple of merges in my scratch repo and of course I can 'merge' my 'dangling branch' even if I actually choose to keep the current working copy, which I'd missed..

So, in my case I can merge H into master and use 'git checkout --ours Main.java' to resolve the conflict - therefore bringing the dangling branch back into line even though the changes in H are actually obsolete since the code was refactored some time after C.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with Commit H? This is the question. Should it be between Commit C and Commit D? Then you can try with `git rebase -i HEAD~7` or `git rebase -i <VersionC>` and move your commit up. But not if anybody else is using the same master branch, you will be banned or fired. Should it be behind Commit I? Then you can (a bit dirty) do `git rebase <CommitI>`, resolve the conflicts and put it as latest version.

So, clearify: who is needing CommitH under which circumstances? Should it have influence on CommitI or G or not? Do others read the repository?

Comment: Commit H is relative to Commit C, but then lets say that in Commit D the code was refactored and the code to which Commit H applies was deleted. I think that the rebase option is out of the question as the master branch is shared between two people.  My limited understanding of rebasing is that it's fine for local un-pushed commits but dangerous and to be avoided for anything which has been pushed back to a remote.
In this case 'who is needing Commit H' : Only a user of Commit C. After that it's obsolete and irrelevant :-)